# Show that the eigenvalues of $A = QTQ^\ast$ are the diagonal entries of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$Q$ is a unitary $n\times n$ matrix of complex numbers. $T$ is an upper triangular 
$n$ x $n$ matrix of complex numbers. $Q^\ast$ is the complex-conjugate transpose of $Q$.

I've tested some sample matrices in MATLAB, but it didn't really give me an understanding of why this holds true. Looking at $A$, there didn't appear to be any noticeable property other than the diagonals all being real numbers, which I don't know is always true.

Comment: $\det(\lambda I -A) = \det(\lambda I - T) = \prod_k (\lambda - [T]_{kk})$.

Comment: Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Since $Q$ is unitary, $Q^{\ast}$ is the inverse of $Q$ and hence $A=QTQ^\ast$ implies that $A$ is similar to $T$. Now, noting that similar matrices preserve eigenvalues and eigenvalues of a triangular matrix are precisely its diagonal entries, can you conclude the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, by properties of the determinant and the fact that here $Q^*=Q^{-1}$ we have
\begin{equation}\det{A}=\det{(QTQ^*)}=\det {Q}\det{T}\det {Q^*}=\det{T}.\end{equation}
Since $T $ is (upper) triangular, its determinant equals the product of its diagonal entries.